# Combine htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess in parent directory :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then i have another .htaccess in a sub directory :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^(.*) /mobile/new_mobile/index.html [NC,L]
```

Each of them separately does its job and works fine, but i want to use them both combined but cant seem to figure out how, i tried both :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^(.*) /mobile/new_mobile/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteRule ^(.*) /mobile/new_mobile/index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this combined .htaccess in site root .htaccess (parent directory):

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^sub/(.*) /mobile/new_mobile/index.html [NC,L]
```